# How to measure disk usage for specific labels in VictoriaMetrics?

Tags: multi-tenant, metrics, victoriametrics

I would like to use [extra_label](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Single-server-VictoriaMetrics.html?highlight=external_label#prometheus-querying-api-enhancements) query parameter to simulate multitenancy through a dedicated custom proxy app.

It seems to work fine but I would also like to be able to measure some things to make sure my users are not writing too much stuff and breaking my server (this project is for the community of a game I play and it will run on my small dedicated server, I'm not a big company).

I would like to:

- Know how much disk space Victoria Metrics is using for a specific `<key>=<value>` pair. (If I could know what file to get the size of, I could use `du` to get the disk usage myself even if VictoriaMetrics doesn't expose this metric)
- Know how many time series have a specific `<key>=<value>` pair. I don't want my users to create too many time series and slow everyone down.
- Know how many data points have a specific `<key>=<value>` pair. Same as above.

I'm pretty sure I can get information about the last two points using some kind of meta query but I don't know the exact details. The first point is the one I'm most interested in but also the one that I'm the least confident is possible.

I know VictoriaMetrics has the Enterprise version with [per-tenant metrics](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/PerTenantStatistic.html) but I obviously can't afford that since I'm not generating one cent of money for this pet project. (That's why I'm trying to simulate multitenancy as best as I can with the free, single-node version)

Answer (score 0):

> Know how much disk space Victoria Metrics is using for a specific = pair

there is no such information, unfortunately. Different time series can be stored in a single file and there is no way of a quick calculating the space used except reading it all.

> Know how many time series have a specific = pair. I don't want my users to create too many time series and slow everyone down.

You can do this via https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#cardinality-explorer
See also https://victoriametrics.com/blog/cardinality-explorer/

> Know how many data points have a specific = pair. Same as above.

VM doesn't track that, because it doesn't really matter from a performance or resource usage perspective. What matters is a number of unique series and there are tools for controlling that https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#cardinality-limiter